# Instruments: Allocations: Is the VM information useful to an iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode5, xcode-instruments

I've got a very large Universal binary. The living bytes in the heap allocations are about what I'd expect
[image: Heap only]

But that are INSANE when you add in the anonymous VM. Is this a cause for concern? How do I start trying to fix VM memory issues?

[image: All allocations]

Comment: http://meandmark.com/blog/2014/01/instruments-heap-allocations-and-anonymous-vm/

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there's anything you can do to reduce the size of the anonymous VM. The operating system reserves the VM for your app and determines how large the VM is.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can control the VM size by reduce 
number of `malloc` objects, raster data or OpenGL/Metal objects.

Things can't reference by name or in memory mapped would show in anonymous VM.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend this session [iOS memory deep dive](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/416/). They can enable the `malloc_stack logging` ; 
[image]

And use `malloc_history` with memory graph to get more info. 
[image]